# How to solve this ordinary differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am just trying to find general solution

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 + \sqrt{1 - xy}$$

Comment: It looks tricky. Do you mind sharing where you came across it, and what you have tried?

Comment: I have tried to solve it by letting u=1-xy, but i could not get the general solution.

Comment: Have you tried maple or mathematica?

Comment: I doubt this has any elementary solution, so some context would be nice to suggest a non-elementary idea (so that we might reduce the ODE to the form of some known special function's ODE).

Comment: i wonder if the one requesting this question to be closed knows how to solve or has anything to contribute to this in a constructive manner.

Comment: That's why I usually ask where the problem come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=-\sqrt{1-xy}$ ,

Then $y=\dfrac{1-u^2}{x}$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{u^2-1}{x^2}-\dfrac{2u}{x}\dfrac{du}{dx}$

$\therefore\dfrac{u^2-1}{x^2}-\dfrac{2u}{x}\dfrac{du}{dx}=1-u$

$\dfrac{2u}{x}\dfrac{du}{dx}=u-1+\dfrac{u^2-1}{x^2}$

Approach $1$:

$\dfrac{2u}{x}\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{(u-1)x^2+(u+1)(u-1)}{x^2}$

$(x^2+u+1)\dfrac{dx}{du}=\dfrac{2ux}{u-1}$

Let $v=x^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dv}{du}=2x\dfrac{dx}{du}$

$\therefore\dfrac{x^2+u+1}{2x}\dfrac{dv}{du}=\dfrac{2ux}{u-1}$

$(x^2+u+1)\dfrac{dv}{du}=\dfrac{4ux^2}{u-1}$

$(v+u+1)\dfrac{dv}{du}=\dfrac{4uv}{u-1}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $w=v+u+1$ ,

Then $v=w-u-1$

$\dfrac{dv}{du}=\dfrac{dw}{du}-1$

$\therefore w\left(\dfrac{dw}{du}-1\right)=\dfrac{4u(w-u-1)}{u-1}$

$w\dfrac{dw}{du}-w=\dfrac{4uw}{u-1}-\dfrac{4u(u+1)}{u-1}$

$w\dfrac{dw}{du}=\dfrac{(5u-1)w}{u-1}-\dfrac{4u(u+1)}{u-1}$

Approach $2$:

$\dfrac{2u}{x}\dfrac{du}{dx}=u-1+\dfrac{u^2-1}{x^2}$

$u\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{u^2}{2x}+\dfrac{xu}{2}-\dfrac{x}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2x}$

Let $u=\sqrt{x}v$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dx}=\sqrt{x}\dfrac{dv}{dx}+\dfrac{v}{2\sqrt{x}}$

$\therefore\sqrt{x}v\left(\sqrt{x}\dfrac{dv}{dx}+\dfrac{v}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)=\dfrac{xv^2}{2x}+\dfrac{x\sqrt{x}v}{2}-\dfrac{x}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2x}$

$xv\dfrac{dv}{dx}+\dfrac{v^2}{2}=\dfrac{v^2}{2}+\dfrac{x\sqrt{x}v}{2}-\dfrac{x}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2x}$

$xv\dfrac{dv}{dx}=\dfrac{x\sqrt{x}v}{2}-\dfrac{x}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2x}$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dx}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x}v}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2x^2}$

Let $t=\dfrac{x^\frac{3}{2}}{3}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dv}{dx}=\dfrac{dv}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{dx}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\dfrac{dv}{dt}$

$\therefore\dfrac{\sqrt{x}v}{2}\dfrac{dv}{dt}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x}v}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2x^2}$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dt}=v-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\dfrac{1}{x^\frac{5}{2}}$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dt}=v-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3t}}-\dfrac{1}{(3t)^\frac{5}{3}}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form.

Please follow the method in https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf or in http://www.iaeng.org/IJAM/issues_v43/issue_3/IJAM_43_3_01.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Here is partial answer. I hope this question doesn't get closed and someone can give a better answer.

I looked at the numerical solution to the initial value problem $$\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 + \sqrt{1-xy}, y(0) = 0$$ the solution exist for only finite time.

The solution must satisfy $$x < y < 2x$$ and these line cut the boundary $xy = 1$ at $(\pm 1, \pm 1), (\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}, \pm \sqrt 2)$ so the interval of existence cannot be bigger than $(-1, 1)$ and no smaller than $(-1/\sqrt 2, 1/\sqrt 2).$

The Runge-Kutta numerical solution I tried stops at $x = 0.75128$.

Comment: @R19, are you aware that that there is a request to close your question? you may want to upvote my "answer" so that it does not get closed.

Comment: I would raise the order of DE to get rid of the radical;  $ 2 (y'-1) y'' + x y' + y = 0 $

Comment: @Narasimham, you need to add to nonlinear de the condition $y^\prime \ge 1.$ still nonlinear and you have a side condition. so i don't know how this is better than the original.

Comment: @abel: Any side condition $ y_i'>1 $ is not correct. From given $ x_i ,y_i $ values and the given de we find out correct  $ y_i' $, to plug it in as initial value.